# Asynchronous execution of parameterized stored procedures using Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, asynchronous

I am using script at [rusanu.com](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) for execution of store dprocedures asynchronously using Service broker.

**Problem :** The script passed name of the stored procedure to call as follows:

```
exec usp_AsyncExecInvoke N'usp_MyLongRunningProcedure', @token output;
```

In this query,   `usp_MyLongRunningProcedure` is the procedure to be executed asynch.

However, How do I modify it to be able to call stored procedures that take input parameters ?

What I have tried:

```
exec usp_AsyncExecInvoke N'POI2Version7.dbo.MatchFirstName=''' + @firstname 
+ ''', @checkbool = ' + cast(@checkbool as nvarchar(10))', @token output;
```

In above statement, `dbo.MatchFirstName` is the procedure to call asynchronously. However, I get a syntax error at + sign already. How I may modify it ?

Comment: Use the link at the top of that page that mentions parameters?: http://rusanu.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-to-a-background-procedure/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Thank you for the link but the script takes values directly while calling Stored procedures, what if I wanted to pass them the variables that contain values and not direct values ? Is ther possible with this script?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this script, I just read the article but in the example you are given `@p1 = 1.0, @n1 = N'@id'`. It's trivial to replace this with `@p1 = @YourParameterInAVariable, @n1 = N'@MyParameterName'`

Comment: Yes, Since i am not well versed with Service broker so just meant to confirm if by any chance connection or scope changes. thank you .